# Interesting question about Borel-sigma algebra and Lebesgue measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $a , b\in \Bbb R$ , $a>0$

$T_{a,b}: \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ defined as:

$T_{a,b}(x)=ax+b$.

Show that

1. $T_{a,b}(B_R)=B_R$

2.$\forall A\in{B_R}$ $m(T_{a,b}(A))=am(A)$

Hints:

Notice that $T_{a,b}$ is bijection and its inverse is $T_{\frac{1}{a},\frac{-b}{a}}$.
First prove that $T_{a,b}$ is a sigma-algebra that contains all the open finite intervals and then look at:

$s: B_R\to [0,\infty]$

$s(A)=am(T^{-1}_{a,b}(A))$
$m$ is Lebesgue measure.

I tries to write:

$T_{a,b}(B_R)={aI+b : I\in B_R}$.

We know that the borel sigma algebra is generated by the collection of open intervals, closed intervals..
It's obvious that $T_{a,b}(B_R)\subset B_R$ as $I\in T_{a,b}(B_R)$ and $I=T_{1,0}$.
Then I have to show that $T_{a,b}(B_R)$ is a sigma-algebra that contain all of the finite segments so by the fact that $B_R$ is the minimal sigma algebra that contains all the finite segments, we get that $B_R\subset T_{a,b}(R)$.
So, we must prove two axioms, T is closed under complements and countable unions.
I tried to use the hint mentioned, but it's not obvious for me how to do it.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, if $T:X\to X$ is any homeomorphism, then $T$ carries Borel sets bijectively to Borel sets. Prove this in the usual way, letting $B=\{T(E):E\in \mathscr B(X)\}$ and showing that $B$ is a $\sigma$-algebra that contains the open sets in $X$:

If $T(E_i)\in B$ then $\bigcup T(E_i)=T\left(\bigcup E_i\right)\in B$ because $\bigcup E_i\in \mathscr B(X).$ A similar argument works for complements.

Now, if $U$ is open in $X$, then $T^{-1}(X)$ is open in $X$ and therefore $T^{-1}(U)\in \mathscr B(X).$ But then $U=T(T^{-1}(U))\in B$ by defnition.

So, $B$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ that contains the open sets. That is, $\mathscr B(X)\subseteq B$. Replacing $T$ by $T^{-1}$ gives the reverse inclusion, so $\mathscr B(X)=B.$

Comment: You proved that for any X, which it can be replace by R, right?  The fact that T is a homeomorphism was not be used in the question?

Comment: @Matematleta , Thanks, it was helpful, can you explain the second part? In addition, for the complement can I say that if $I\in B$ so I=T(E) then $I^c=(T(E)^c=T(E^c)$ where $E^c\in B(x)$ ? Can we say that $T^{-1}(U)$ is open in X since T is continuos?

Comment: @Matematleta can you explain it?

Comment: @ Almaa @  user726608 If $A\in B$ then $A=T(E)$ for some Borel set $E$. Now, as $T$ is a homeomophism, $T^{-1}$ is continuous, so $(T^{-1})^{-1}=T$ carries Borel sets to Borel sets. That is, $A=T(E)\in \mathscr B(X).$

Answer (score 2):

For the first question, you can prove something more general( also more clean so see)
**Lemma** : For any function between two space $f: A \rightarrow B$, we have: $ f^{-1}( \sigma(S))= \sigma (f^{-1}(S))$ , where $S$ is any family of subsets of $B$.
The first question is the direct consequence of the above lemma by using $f(x)= \frac{x-b}{a}$
For the second question, we denote the righthand side measure as $\mu_2$, the lefthand side measure as $\mu_1$, they clearly equal on any elements in the semiring $ S=\{ (a,b] : a<b\}$, hence by the unicity of Caratheodory's extension theorem (+ the $\sigma$-finiteness), we get the equality.

**Hints for lemma**: 
You can firstly prove the $LHS$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, then the inclusion $ RHS \subset LHS$ is clear. 
For the other direction, you define $P:= \{ A | f^{-1}(A) \in \sigma( f^{-1}(S))\}$ , that is the familiy of set $A$ such that $f^{-1}(A) \in \sigma( f^{-1}(S))$. So what is left to do is proving that $ \sigma(S) \subset P$.  So do this, you prove that $S \subset P$ and $P$ is a sigma algebra.

P/s: I assume that you are familiar with monotone class argument.

Comment: @Paresseux Nguyen can you give more information for the 2nd part..

Comment: I tried to do it many times but still not working:(

Comment: @Almaa : Okay. Let $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ be two functions such that: $$\mu_1(A)= \mu( T(A)) ; \mu_2(A)= a\mu(A)$$
Clearly, $\mu_1 $ and $\mu_2$ are two measures. ( $\mu_1$ is an image measure, $\mu_2$ is just a multiplication from a given measure)<br>
Besides,$$\mu_1( (u,v] ) =a(v-u) =\mu_2( (u,v])$$
(By calculation), so $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are identical on the element of the semiring $B=\{ (u,v] \}$ <br> .Furthurmore, $\mu_2$ is $\sigma$-finite, hence by unicity of Caratheodory's extension theorem. We're done.

Comment: @Almaa : Okay. Let $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ be two functions such that: $$\mu_1(A)= \mu( T(A)) ; \mu_2(A)= a\mu(A)$$
Clearly, $\mu_1 $ and $\mu_2$ are two measures. ( $\mu_1$ is an image measure, $\mu_2$ is just a multiplication from a given measure)<br>
Besides,$$\mu_1( (u,v] ) =a(v-u) =\mu_2( (u,v])$$
(By calculation), so $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are identical on the element of the semiring $B=\{ (u,v] \}$ <br> .Furthurmore, $\mu_2$ is $\sigma$-finite, hence by unicity of Caratheodory's extension theorem. We're done.

Comment: In fact, you can also use the monotone class argument to solve the second part ( if you are familiar with it) , but just considering the famility:<br>
$$S:= \{ A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})  | \mu_1(A)=\mu_2(A)\}$$
You can prove that $S$ is a $sigma$-algebra, that contains all open interval $(u,v)$<br>
Hence $ \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})  \subset S$, and that is:
$$ \mu_1(A)= \mu_2(A)$$ for all $A$ measurable.

Comment: Thanks, S is a sigma algebra:let A in S so A in B(R) and also $\mu(T(A^c))=\mu(T(A))^c= (\mu(T(A))^c=(a\mu(A))^c=a\mu(A^c)$ and I can do same approach for showing that S is closed under countable unions.$\mu(T(c,d))=\mu(ac+b,ad+b)=\mu(ac+b,ad+b]\setminus{ad+b}$ then saying that $\mu({ad+b})=0$ and continue getting that S contains all the open intervals thus It containd B(R)?
Or can I do what as above for an interval (u,v], since B(R) is also generated by the collection of the ${(u,v], u<v}$ ? I couldn't understand how to use the $\sigma$ finite and the theorm to conclude in the 1 method

Comment: @Paresseux Nguyen using the fact that the measure of a singleton {ad+b} is zero

Comment: @Almaa :  Your last reply was unedited so I didn't check it. Yeah you can do that to show the continuity, also you noticed what I had overlooked. I didn't pay attention that these measures are sigma-finite, not finite. And this makes $S$ no longer a dynkin system. Sorry about that. (though we can always fix that problem but that will lead to unnessary complification of our solution)

Comment: So let's stick with Caratheodory's approach then. Here is the Caratheodory's theorem in sigma finite case. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_extension_theorem <br> So you see, $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are the extensions of the same measure on a semiring. And because they are sigma finite, hence due to the unicity of extension, $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ must be identical.

Comment: @Paresseux Nguyen For showing that the S is a sigma algebra , is it true that: if $A\in S$ then $A\in B(R)$ and $\mu_2(A^c)=\mu(T(A^c))=a\mu(A^c)=(a\mu(A))^c=\mu_1(A^c)$ that shows that S is closed under complements.

Comment: It is true if $\mu_1( \Omega)=\mu_1( \Omega)<+\infty$, and wrong otherwise.

Comment: In our case, for solving using the sigma-algebra, can we say that?

Comment: No, we can't that kind of complement argument when measures are infinite.